# How can LabVIEW be validated for use in medical device testing

Tags: labview, medical

We are working on a medical devices test system and as part of the system we must unit test the code.

NI is an ISO 9000 company and as such I had assumed that LabVIEW was standardized but it appears it is not, from wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages

Do I now need to unit test every function I am going to use?
Is there a recommended path for developing medical device systems in an ISO 13485 manner?

Comment: http://www.ni.com/medical/

Answer (score 2):

National Instruments is indeed ISO-9001 certified. This has nothing to do with LabVIEW (the G language for that matter) to be standardized it is their proprietary and they do not have to standardize it in any way.

The level of testing of your code depends heavily on the safety class of the software. There are three safety classes A, B and C as per IEC-62304. 
IEC-62304 will in great detail outline the level of effort that you must take to test your code.
Safety class 
C - is the most stringent and will require the most effort & documentation.

If LabVIEW is used in order to test the validity the medical device code, and is not part of the medical device itself I do not believe you need to provide any additional effort in testing the test code.

But again the level of effort will depend heavily on the safety classification of code under test.